# Is there anything wrong/dangerous about reassigning function parameters?

Tags: javascript

Is there anything I should be worried about if I write code like below. I was always told that reassigning function params was a big no-no in Javascript.

```
function getAddress(address, lowerCase) {
  address = { ...address }

  if (lowerCase) {
    address.line1 = address.line1.toLowerCase();
    address.city = address.city.toLowerCase();
  }

  return address;
}
```

Examples of advice:

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign
- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/10/javascript-don-t-reassign-your-function-arguments/

Comment: It's at most an issue of style or "coding standards"; the language does not care.

Comment: Told by whom? What reason did they give for it being bad?

Comment: Source for advice to not reassign added

Comment: Probably a more appropriate question for code review and not so much Stack Overflow.

Comment: The first link is for eslint (irrelevant) and the second is from ten years ago...

Comment: I second Martin's comment. This question would be more appropriate on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the reason why some places recommend not reassigning function parameters is that doing so will also change the `arguments` object, which is not necessarily expected behaviour. For functions that don't use `arguments`, however, this should not be an issue.

For example, consider the following:

```
function getAddress(address, lowerCase) {
    address = { ...address };

    var originalAddress = arguments[0];

    // Do stuff with address
}
```

For someone not familiar with how JavaScript works in this respect, it might be reasonable to assume that setting `originalAddress` like this would record the original first argument that was passed to the function. But actually, when `address` is reassigned, this also mutates the relevant record in `arguments`.

Even when you're not using the `arguments` object, it can be a useful practice to consider all arguments to a function to be constant and immutable, to avoid potentially introducing bugs such as through modifying an object that is passed to a function. In your example, this could be achieved like this:

```
function getAddress(addressArg, lowerCase) {
  const address = { ...addressArg }

  if (lowerCase) {
    address.line1 = address.line1.toLowerCase();
    address.city = address.city.toLowerCase();
  }

  return address;
}
```

In your implementation, so long as `address` only contains primitive properties (as opposed to properties that point to a reference value such as an object or an array) then your copying it through `{ ...address }` should create a completely separate copy. However, this method only creates a shallow copy.

If `address` does contain object or array properties, but no properties that are classes or functions, then you could create a deep copy through `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(address))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view,
If address is an complex data type like object or an array, changing it in the function would mean changing the original object which might not be the intention or needed and introduce a bug

If the param is a primitive data type, it would create a copy in the scope of the function..so it should not be a problem

Comment: The question is about reassigning function arguments, not about setting their properties. Even if a function argument is a reference to an object or an array, rather than being a primitive, assigning it to a new value won't directly affect that referenced value.